# Why do values change when casting a function pointer? (msvc ver20)

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

To test storing a value in a text segment, I wrote the code below.
The value of 'foo' and the value of 'v', 'bar' are different when viewed using debugging. Normal functions without '__declspec(naked)' also have their values changed.
When debugging memory using the address of 'foo', '12345678' is displayed well.
I'd appreciate it if you could tell me why the values change.

edit:
When I checked again, the only thing that the 'foo' value displayed in debugging was different from the value or output of the program. But I still don't know why it's different.

code:

```cpp
__declspec(naked) void foo() {
    __asm {
        _emit 0x78
        _emit 0x56
        _emit 0x34
        _emit 0x12
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << sizeof(&foo) << '\n';

    void (*bar)() = foo;
    cout << bar << '\n';

    void* v = (void*)(&foo);
    cout <<  v << '\n';

    unsigned* p = (unsigned*)(v);
    cout << p << '\n';

    unsigned a = *p;
    cout << hex <<  a;

    cout << (void(*)())foo;
    cout << foo;
}
```

[image]

output:

```
4
00EA1357
00EA1357
00EA1357
00EA1357
00EA1357
c74e9
```

Comment: If you disassemble at where `bar` points, you'll see that it's an incremental linking thunk. The name of a function is not required to point to the first byte of code in the function, and in your case, it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't this an aliasing violation and therefore UB?

Comment: @AndyG If the thunk is used consistently for all function pointers, then there is no violation.

Comment: I mistakenly thought you'd had to guarantee that the integer type being cast to was large enough (e.g. use intptr_t if available) instead it's implementation defined if the integer type is not big enough (per expr.reinterpret_cast)

Comment: Build the Release build. In Debug build, the compiler generates a stub that jumps to the actual function; `foo` points to that stub. Possibly to make it easier to set breakpoints, or something. In Release build, your program prints the expected `12345678`